# Using pgfkeys as an argument to a macro

Tags: macros, pgfkeys

I would like to use pgfkeys in a macro but find the documentation a bit hard to get started with. The following code should illustrate the problem I am trying to solve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[2][]{
  Before the elements.
  % if the elements key is set and the list is not empty
  % extract the members and list them separated by commas...
  % else print `No elements passed.'
  #2
}

\begin{document}

\mymacro[elements={a, b, c}]{Foo.}

% The above should expand to:
%
% Before the elements. a, b, c. Foo.

\mymacro{Foo.}

% The above should expand to:
%
% Before the elements. No elements passed. Foo.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit:** This is a modified answer based on the comments.  I've adopted a bunch of suggestions that Andrew Stacey made.

The PGF key facilities are so varied and powerful that it takes a fair amount of effort to figure out how to use them to do what you want!  Let me present my solution in pieces and then in full.

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[2][elements/.initial = {No elements passed.}]{
  Before the elements.
  % if the elements key is set and the list is not empty
  % extract the members and list them separated by commas...
  % else print `No elements passed.'
  {\pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd, #1, print}}
  #2
}
```

Here is how you should define `\mymacro`.  You must call `\pgfkeys` on your optional argument, in order that the keys you want to use actually be processed.  Note that it's necessary to give your keys a "directory" in the path tree of all PGF keys, and it seems like good form to make your own, which I've called `/mymacro` (like a UNIX directory).

The way things will work is that `elements` will process the value it is given and then `print` will output the result, or the error message if no elements were specified.  I handle this by having the default argument for `\mymacro` simply set the value of `elements` directly, without any processing.

I am also careful to put the call to `\pgfkeys` in a group, since the action of `elements` doesn't initialize its value and subsequent calls of `\mymacro` could interfere with each other.

```
\pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd,
 print/.code = {\pgfkeysvalueof{/mymacro/elements}},
 elements/.code = {%
  \pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd,
           list/.list = {#1},
           elements/.add={\{}{\}}
  }%
 },
 list/.code = {\pgfkeys{/mymacro/elements/.append = (#1)}}
}
```

Now we have to define the action of these keys.  As I see it, your `elements` key is a storage bin, and whatever is in it will get printed by `print`.  However, it *also* processes the value it receives when it is called as `elements = {a, b, ...}`, using the `.code` subkey ("handler") I define for it.  This thing calls the `list` key's `.list` handler (which requires the `pgffor` package if you are just loading `pgfkeys` on its own rather than through `tikz`), which just loops over whatever comma-separated list it is given, applying `list/.code` to each item.  As an uncreative example, I have this just put parentheses around the items.  Afterwards, you can also have `elements/.code` postprocess the result, for example by pre- and app-ending braces.

This trick of having a key act both as storage for a value and code to act on that value is quite useful.  At the very least it allows you to write semantically appealing statements like `elements = {a,b,c}` without worrying whether that is *really* an assignment, since it can be both code and a subsequent assignment of the processed result.

It is probably possible to set things up more cleverly so that fewer keys are used, but that would be confusing in this example.  Here is the full LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[2][elements/.initial = {No elements passed.}]{
  Before the elements.
  % if the elements key is set and the list is not empty
  % extract the members and list them separated by commas...
  % else print `No elements passed.'
  {\pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd, #1, print}}
  #2
}

\pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd,
 print/.code = {\pgfkeysvalueof{/mymacro/elements}},
 elements/.code = {%
  \pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd,
           list/.list = {#1},
           elements/.add={\{}{\}}
  }%
 },
 list/.code = {\pgfkeys{/mymacro/elements/.append = (#1)}}
}

\begin{document}
\mymacro[elements = {a,b,c}]{Foo}

\mymacro{Bar}

\mymacro[elements = {1,2,3}]{Baz}

\mymacro{Quh}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you didn't have the `elements` key adding the braces then you could shorten that a bit with `elements/.initial={No elements passed}` and make your macro have its own group (so that any changes to `/mymacro/elements` is local to the macro.  Or you could have the `print` key with a `default` option of `No elements passed` ... as you say, the possibilities are endless!

Comment: @Andrew: I struggled with the notion of using a default option, but I realized that it might impede generalizing the action of `elements`.  Here is another crazy way using only one key: give `\mymacro` a default argument of "`elements`", run just `\pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd, #1}`, and have `elements/.code` print its own value, with a suitable `.default`.  This doesn't generalize, though, without more fiddling than it's worth not to just use several keys.

Comment: Fair point.  In the balance between clarity and number of keys I'd always go for number of keys.  But one thing that keeps catching me out is that if one wants to store a value in a key then that key has to be initialised, say via an initial value.  That's partly what was on my mind when I suggested an `.initial` syntax.

Comment: @Andrew: A useful trick I came up with recently is to use the `.unknown` handler to void that requirement.  Just write, say, `/mymacro/.unknown/.code = {\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname}{#1}}`, and then the first time you write `/mymacro/some key = value`, it means what you expect.  You can go further and have `.unknown` also set up a `.code` for the key, so that the *second* time you call it something else happens.  You can have that action modify `some key/.code` again...

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the superb explanation. One question still remains though: the value of the elements key should be treated as a list and looped over, not as a string. Possible?

Comment: @Ryan: That's a useful trick.  I'll have to remember that one.  As for the looping, there is the `.list` handler in `pgfkeys` that allows one to execute the code for each value in a comma-separated list.  That might be of use.

Comment: @Ryan great answer and good comments. Consider moving some of the comments in the answer, especially on the loops.

Comment: @Yiannis: I'm on it!

Answer (score 6):

The solution depends on what you want to do with elements but an idea is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\def\mymacroempty{}

\pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd,
elements/.code = \def\myelements{#1}}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[2][]{%
\pgfkeys{/mymacro/.cd,elements={}}
\pgfqkeys{/mymacro}{#1}   
\ifx\myelements\mymacroempty 
   No elements passed.
\else 
\myelements.
\fi
  #2
}

\begin{document}

\mymacro[elements={a, b, c}]{Foo.}

\mymacro{Foo.}

\end{document}
```

[image]